# Triggers of ModelContextChange event

Tags: sapui5

I have seen something like this in a code that I maintain:

> ```xml
> <Button
>   xmlns="sap.m"
>   press=".btnCopyPress"
>   modelContextChange=".btnCopyContext"
> />
> ```

However, even while reading the API reference about [`modelContextChange`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#events/modelContextChange), which states that this event is *fired when models or contexts are changed on this object*: is this event triggered each time when the container is showing something different? As far as I know, when I add `alert(something)`, the event only triggers when I select/switch between say customers.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not fired when the data changes per se. The binding context relates to the current oData path or JSON path attached to the control, for instance entity `Person('1234')`. If the data of that person changes, the context or the model itself doesn't change since it's still relevant to `Person('1234')`.

If the element is bound to a different context, like a different person, I'd expect the event to fire as per your observations.